# Call a Console App from ASP.NET MVC, but don't want to wait for the response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, console, system.diagnostics

**I am trying to achieve something like this.**

```
    private Process p;

    //
    // GET: /Home/
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new Contents() { Text = "Hello" });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Processing()
    {
        // Get the file path of your Application (exe)
        string filePath = @"Z:\Junk\MVCtoConsole\Sample Console App\bin\Debug\Sample Console App.exe";

        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(filePath);
        info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;

        p = Process.Start(info);
        p.WaitForExit(1);

        Session["pid"] = p.Id;

        return View("Index", new Contents() { Text = "Processing" });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Kill()
    {
        int pid = (int)Session["pid"];

        p = Process.GetProcessById(pid);

        p.Kill();

        return View("Index", new Contents() { Text = "Killed" });
    }

    public ActionResult Update()
    {
        int pid = (int)Session["pid"];

        p = Process.GetProcessById(pid);

        return View("Index", new Contents() { Text = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() });
    }
```

**But I get the following errors when calling the update view...**

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> StandardOut has not been redirected or
>   the process hasn't started yet.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.InvalidOperationException:
>   StandardOut has not been redirected or
>   the process hasn't started yet.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 56:             p =
>   Process.GetProcessById(pid); Line 57: 
>   Line 58:             return
>   View("Index", new Contents() { Text =
>   p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() }); Line
>   59:         } Line 60:     }
>
> Source File:
>   Z:\Junk\MVCtoConsole\MVCtoConsole\Controllers\HomeController.cs
>   Line: 58
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException:
>   StandardOut has not been redirected or
>   the process hasn't started yet.]
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.get_StandardOutput()
>   +1172937    MVCtoConsole.Controllers.HomeController.Update()
>   in
>   Z:\Junk\MVCtoConsole\MVCtoConsole\Controllers\HomeController.cs:58
>   lambda_method(ExecutionScope ,
>   ControllerBase , Object[] ) +40
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +17
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +178
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor
>   actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +24
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClassd.b*_a()
>   +52    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext
>   preContext, Func`1 continuation) +254 
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassf.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__c()
>   +19    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters,
>   ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
>   IDictionary`2 parameters) +192
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName)
>   +314    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
>   +105    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +39
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +7
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4()
>   +34    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
>   +21    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult
>   _) +12    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>   +59    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +44
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +7
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +8690318    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   +155
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:2.0.50727.5446;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5420

**Any Ideas as to how this can be achieved?**

**Oh my console app isn't doing very much just now, as I am just trying to find out if this will work.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Sample_Console_App
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Triggered");

            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i = i + 100)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you make it a DLL rather than Console app and then just use DLLImport attribute

Comment: Would that use the same memory pool as IIS? The reason I want to do it this way is to prevent a large import having an effect on the sites running in IIS.

Comment: Can IIS User start process on the machine?

Comment: Yes it starts the application and can get the standardoutput if I use p.Start(), but that won't continue through the method until the console app has finished.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set also

p.UseShellExecute = False

Sorry didn't saw that you already set it

you should check p state before asking for output could be already ended by that time