# Assigning a web address to a function

Tags: rest, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, fortran

Sorry if I did not express myself clearly. I need to: Make a function accessible from HTTP(S) communication, which means a web address should be assigned to my function. Users can send inputs in the proper format to initiate this function.

Currently, the functions are written in FORTRAN, which means I could not put them to Google App Engine. My approaches are:

1. Upload FORTRAN codes to this cloud server and compile it into executable file.
2. 'Publish' this compiled FORTRAN code, which will give it a web address.
3. Allow users to send inputs to this address and do some calculation.
4. Save computation results to AMAZON S3 and generate a link for users to download.

So my question is that what is the name of this feature (I guess it is REST) ? Is there any big cloud server can provide this service (like AMAZON, GOOGLE)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What is the name of this feature?  Its called a web service, also known as a Web API.

There's a really good explaination here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/

A web service is more or less exactly the same as a website (runs on a web server, uses HTTP) but it returns data only, usually XML or JSON, no graphics or formatting.

As for hosting, as I said there's basically no difference between hosting a web service and hosting a web page.  At the application level a web service returns only data, whereas a website returns an HTML formatted web page.  And when you consider that HTML (XHTML) is actually a subset of XML, there's actually no difference at all between a website and a web service - the only difference is the consumer: one is intended to look nice and be consumed by a person reading a web page, the other returns only data and is intended to be consumed by some kind of client application.

== Edit ==

Fortran has been around a lot longer than the internet.  It was the first High Level Programming language.... I think developed in the 1950's, so about 20 years before the internet.  You're not going to find anyone that can host a Fortran web service or application.  Maybe consider rewriting in Python if you require web interaction - they're quite similar.  Alternatively, most of the web languages support calling a console application:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

[Call a Console App from ASP.NET MVC, but don't want to wait for the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490666/call-a-console-app-from-asp-net-mvc-but-dont-want-to-wait-for-the-response)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to expose some piece of functionality on a computer as a **web service**.  Specifically, if you want it to behave as if your actually calling a specific function on the computer, it might be a **remote procedure call**.

Many factors would lead to choosing what vendor to use, if you're looking for a cloud base solution, I would determine if there's a specific language you want to use, and look at what solutions can support that.  Beyond that, each has different support and pricing models.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I have update this tread and provide some details.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a VPS type of service.  I removed Google App Engine since it currently can't run Fortran code.  You will be looking at Amazon EC2 or just getting a VPS from some web hosting company like GoDaddy, BlueHost, HostGator etc depending on your likely usage.

Depending on what you have experience with you could do this with Python, Ruby, or PHP.  They all have strong web frameworks and can call executables on the local system such as a Fortran compiler.  So you would write the web code in a framework like Django or Rails then call your local cgi to execute the Fortran code and return the results via the framework.

Other suggestions:
You might want to look at using [Pypy](http://pypy.org/) and python for the computations it can do almost as much as Fortran but is a bit more modern.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no business sense for any cloud provider to try to "support" Fortran. Besides, Fortran is so "awesome", it's really difficult to support.

Strategies:

1. Create web services in another language/framework and then invoke Fortran code via CLI calls.
2. Use Fortran wrappers and advanced toolkits (e.g Fortran for .NET) to create the web services.
3. Compile Fortran code down to native code (e.g .dll) and invoke from Java using JNA then use Java Web Services to create REST/SOAP WS for the functions. This can be achieved easily using Netbeans IDE.

Personally, I would consider going with option 3.

These are some of those things I classify as "stunts" so I'll automatically rule AppEngine out.
I would do this on a box (or virtual box) where I can get root access and do whatever I want (there are plenty of these).

Here are some resources.

Calling Fortran from Java using Java Native Access: http://oms.javaforge.com/wiki/66061

Calling Fortran from Java using JNI: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~anderson/JAVAclass/JavaInterface/JavaInterface.html

Fortran for .NET using Lahey/Fujitsu Fortran Enterprise: http://www.lahey.com/lf71/lf71.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here's a web application written in Fortran: https://github.com/rlcarino/heeds. 
The Fortran program communicates with the nginx webserver via FastCGI. Data for the program is stored in text files; no 'formal' database is used.

Live runs of the program may be found in http://heeds.csu.edu.ph/. The application is running on a server in the cloud. Some users connect to it without cell data cost via Android smartphones running Free Basics which is available in that part of the world.

Comment: You should probably disclose that you are the author of this software.